# Zend Framework -- Simple bootstrap edit causing application to fail

Tags: php, zend-framework, bootstrapping

I'm working through the Zend Framework 1.8 Web Development book, and I'm at the part that describes how you can edit the bootstrap.php to initialize a doctype for you.  However, when I insert the function, I get a server error when I navigate to my project.

The application only breaks after I add the following code to my Bootstrap.php

```
<?php

class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{

    protected function _initViewSettings()
    {
        $this->bootstrap('view');
        $view = $this->getResource('view');
        $view->doctype('XHTML1_STRICT');
    }

}
```

Comment: HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request. And when I take the function out, the page loads my view just fine.

Comment: Can you narrow it down further, to just one line?

Comment: It looks to be the last line of the function

Comment: Hmm maybe it's changed since 1.8.  I guess the proper syntax now is         $doctypeHelper = new Zend_View_Helper_Doctype();
        $doctypeHelper->doctype('XHTML1_STRICT');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matthew's article on this topic made things very clear for me:

http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/230-Quick-Start-to-Zend_Application_Bootstrap.html

I recommend reading the whole article as well as the linked manual page:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html

So if you are initializing the view, you could do something like this:

```
protected function _initView()
{
    $view = new Zend_View();
    $view->doctype('XHTML1_STRICT');
    // do other stuff to the view...
    return $view;
}
```

What the others are saying is correct. However, I found the methods described by Matthew and using the application.ini as well to provide the cleanest bootstrap. Please do read the article as it explains dependencies and naming conventions.

It also seems like you do not have your error reporting settings configured to display detailed errors. If you change this, you will see a more concise error, rather than just the general HTTP 500.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the view resource in your config. Otherwise, there will be no `view` resource. It's also good to set the view encoding so kill two birds with one stone

```
resources.view.encoding = "UTF-8"
```

I have the following in my `Bootstrap.php` file (ZF 1.11.4) and it works just fine

```
protected function _initDoctype()
{
    $this->bootstrap('view');

    /* @var $view Zend_View */
    $view = $this->getResource('view');

    $view->doctype(Zend_View_Helper_Doctype::HTML5);
}
```